# UITableView put text on top of image

Tags: uitableview, cell

I have a `UITableView` that has an image and text on each cell, however they are put side by side. What I'm trying to do is put the text label over the top of the image. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take custom `UITableViewCell`,where take `UIView` at every cell and make your image as the background color of the `UIView` then take a `UILabel` at the top of the `UIView`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pl_arows.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,290, 70)] autorelease]; //important do not changer the position
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"order_description_bg.png"]];
    cellView.tag =10;
     [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 39, 36)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_category.png"];
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    imgView.tag = 5;
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];

    //Status label

            CGRect statusRectText = CGRectMake(52, 0, 50, 18);
    UILabel *statusLabelText = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRectText] autorelease];
    statusLabelText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            statusLabelText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    statusLabelText.tag = 101;
     [imgView addSubview:statusLabelText];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to define a custom `UITableViewCell` in which you can place any standard UI objects, including a `UILabel` on top of your `UIImage`.